# Having issue summarising python dataframe to one line per record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I've got a dataframe in the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b'],'var':[1,2,3,5,9]})
```

and I'm trying to reshape it so that there is one line per 'id' and the values 'var' are displayed across in one line, so 'a' would have 1,2,3 ... 'b' would have '5,9'

I've tried with:

```
test = pd.crosstab(df.id, df.var)  # but it does not work?
```

If someone could help me it would be much appreciated

EDIT, I enclose the desired results as a picture here[image]

Comment: as @ayhan has mention in [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355717/having-problelm-summarising-python-dataframe-to-one-line-per-record/39355758#comment66041700_39355875) - `pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['var'])` should do the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [32]: df.groupby('id')['var'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.cat(sep=',')).reset_index()
Out[32]:
  id    var
0  a  1,2,3
1  b    5,9
```

or having `var` as a list:

```
In [29]: df.groupby('id')['var'].apply(list).reset_index()
Out[29]:
  id        var
0  a  [1, 2, 3]
1  b     [5, 9]
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can use `pivot_table()` which is used by `crosstab()` method internally?

```
In [26]: df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='var', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
Out[26]:
var  1  2  3  5  9
id
a    1  1  1  0  0
b    0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks all for your help but sorry this is not what i was after. i actually want the final output to look like this: a 1 2 3 then b woulhave the values : 5   9 etc So instead of having 1 and 0 flags we would have the actual values.. (1 2 3 for a and 5 9 for b)

Comment: @tezzaaa, could you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39355717/edit) your desired data set in your question?

Comment: Hi, I just did. Sorry i was struggling with pasting formats in the post section. I uploaded a pic :-)

Comment: that's brilliant thank you so much. I'm really really grateful

Comment: hi, how do i do this / i cant see the option? I voted already but i cant see any button to accept answer..?

Comment: @tezzaaa, you are welcome! :) Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You must supply the correct arguments, like:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['id'], columns=df['var'])

var  1  2  3  5  9
id                
a    1  1  1  0  0
b    0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Yes, dot notation creates problems because `.var` is a method defined on dataframe.